# how to deal with arguments when executing a script

Tags: bash, shell-script

how to deal with arguments when executing a script

my code is:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$1"

if [ DIR eq $1 ]
then
    echo -n "total directories:" ; find $DIR -type d | wc -l
    echo -n "total files:" ; find $DIR -type f | wc -l
else
    echo " pass parameters"
fi
```

when I executed with the script name (`./countfiledirs`) it's showing as:

```
./countfiledirs: line 4: [: DIR: unary operator expected
 pass parameters
```

If I execute `./countfiledirs` without passing arguments it should have to show like:

```
pls pass arguments.
```

If I execute ./countfiledirs with passing arguments as ./countfiledirs /usr/share it should have to show output like:

```
total directories:145
total files:254
```

Comment: Try to change it: if [ "$DIR" = $1 ] eq, actually -eq is for numbers

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200295/100397 for the (working) code on which this broken sample is based

Comment: quote all your variable uses in all you bash scripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
if [ DIR eq $1 ]
```

You are not using the variable, that's the simple string `DIR`. What you want is:

```
if [ "$DIR" = "$1" ]
```

However, since you are setting `DIR="$1"`, that test will always be true by definition. Also, when `$1` is empty, so will `$DIR` and the `find` command will be run on the current directory. For many versions of `find`, these commands are equivalent:

```
find . -name foo
find -name foo
```

In the absence of a target directory, `find` will search through `.`, the current directory. So, a working version of your script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Avoid using UPPER CASE variable names in bash.
dir="$1"

## Check if $dir exists
if [ -e "$dir" ]
then
    printf "total directories: %s\n" $(find "$dir" -type d | wc -l)
    printf "total files: %s\n" $(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l)
else
    echo " pass parameters"
fi
```

The number of arguments passed to a bash script is saved as `$#`, so you could also do

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
    echo "pass parameters"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: It's always a good practice to check the numbers of parameters (if your script needs one)